# Careers: Filter by Country (by default?)

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I live in Northern Vermont. Whenever I do a careers search, I have to wade through a bunch of search results in Quebec. It's a lovely place to visit, I just can't effectively work there. It'd be great if I could see the relevant jobs in say, New Hampshire and New York, without the ones in Montreal.

I think it'd be even better if it defaulted to showing results in your country first. I would imagine this is more of an issue in Europe, although crossing the border is much easier there.

So I'd request either:

1. Hide other countries by default (or choice), with an option to display them
2. Show results from your own country nearer the top (weighted more by country than by distance).

Example:

[image: Careers out of country]

And the result I'm interested in is right down below here. Followed by 6 more QC jobs.

Comment: Maybe this isn't a problem for other people, since there are presumably more than 12 postings elsewhere in the world.